# MVC5 Authorization for bundles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I am using Application_PostAcquireRequestState method in global.asax.cs to verify the user role with some custom roles check Authorize attribute [MyAuthorize Roles="Player"]

HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl  has "/bundles/modernizr?v=zzz"

I do not want this method call for all bundles.

The event is triggered for all urls including js and css bundles. Is there any cleaner way to defer Application_PostAcquireRequestState for bundles?
I did try web.config in /scripts folder and `<location path="bundles">` with allow *.
bundles is not a folder anyway and may be that's the reason "`<location>`" did not work.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: why not do that on controller level?

Comment: Do you mean that there is no way of avoiding the trigger of PostAquireRequestState for js bundles?

Comment: do the authorized attribute in controller and you wont have this problem